# Stop endless while True loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

The following program causes an endless loop. How do I stop the while from continuing once I've read in all the links? Thank you.

```
def findAllURLs():

    with open('manylinks.html', 'r') as f:
        data = f.read()
        start = data.find('href')
        while(True):
            begin = data.find('"',start)
            end = data.find('"',begin+1)
            print data[begin+1:end]
            start = data.find('href',end + 1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    findAllURLs()
```

Comment: By using a `break` statement...

Comment: You can also `return` (or use `break` as suggested). You may want to use something like `beautifulsoup` to parse html.

Comment: A perfect example of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify your code this way :

```
def findAllURLs():

    with open('manylinks.html', 'r') as f:
        data = f.read()
        start = data.find('href')
        while(start != -1):
            begin = data.find('"',start)
            end = data.find('"',begin+1)
            print data[begin+1:end]
            start = data.find('href',end + 1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    findAllURLs()
```

Indeed, `find` will return -1 when it can't find any additional matches, and hence end the `while` loop.

Comment: Thank you 3kt! Based on you response I added while(True): if(start == -1): break.

Comment: This works too, but as shown in my answer you can merge both statements in `while(start != -1):`, which will have the exact same behavior.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use a `while` loop, provided that you are using proper tools to parse HTML. I recommend that you use the [BeautifulSoup 4](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4) library to parse the document:

```
import bs4

def find_all_urls():    
    with open('manylinks.html', 'r') as f:
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(f)

    for i in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        print(i['href'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    find_all_urls()
```

This would find only `<a>` elenments with `href`, omitting `<link href=>` for example. If you want `link` elements too, use `soup.find_all(href=True)`